# Positive unbounded operator with zero not as an eigenalue

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

I am currently doing Quantum Mechanics and I am supposed to show that zero is an eigenvalue of a positive operator. I have no knowledge of Functional Analysis at that kind of level, so I was wondering whether there is somebody who has some knowledge about these kind of operators and could for example list a few properties that these kind of operators have, so that I could find a contradiction? This operator is given by $N=A^*A$, where $A$ is another unbounded operator.

Comment: Are you supposed to show that zero is *always* an eigenvalue of a positive unbounded operator or that zero *can* be an eigenvalue of a positive unbounded operator?

Comment: i am just supposed to show that it can be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be, "Show that zero *can be* a nontrivial eigenvalue of a positive unbounded operator." To do this, modify Martin Argerami's answer: Choose an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of your Hilbert space and define $Ne_n = (n-1)e_n$. This in particular has $Ne_1 = 0 = 0e_1$, so $0$ is a nontrivial eigenvalue.

(This operator $N$ is positive its eigenvalues are positive. Also, $N = A^*A$ for the operator $A$ defined by $Ae_n = \sqrt{n-1}e_n$.)

This is an important observation because positive *bounded* operators cannot have zero as a nontrivial eigenvalue. Being positive for a bounded symmetric operator $T$ is the same as saying that for any nonzero $x$, $\langle Tx,x\rangle > 0$. In particular, if $x$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector of $T$, then $$0 < \langle Tx,x\rangle = \lambda\|x\|^2,$$ so $\lambda > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Having zero as an eigenvalue is a synonym of having non-trivial kernel. But you can easily have a positive operator that is injective, i.e. such that zero is not an eigenvalue. For example, fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and let $Ne_n=ne_n$.

Answer (score 0):

For $A$ as you state, if $A^{\star}Af=0$ for some non-zero $f$ in the space, then
$$
      0 = (A^{\star}Af,f) = (Af,Af)=\|Af\|^{2},
$$
implies that $Af=0$. So the null space of $A^{\star}A$ is the same as the null space of $A$. This has a definite effect on the ground state solutions. For example, consider $H=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on the domain consisting of twice continuously differentiable functions $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ with periodic function and first derivative. This operator is $A^{\star}A$ where $A=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ is defined on the domain of continuously differentiable periodic functions on $[0,2\pi]$. The eigenvalues of $H$ are $0,1^{2},2^{2},3^{2},\ldots$. For $\lambda = n^{2}$ for $n > 0$, there are two linearly-independent eigenfunctions. However, for $n=0$, the ground state solution is reduced to the null space of $A$, which is a lower-order differential operator. The constant function is, up to a multiplicative constant, the only eigenfunction for eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: You should be carefule about that example - domain issues on that one are really crucial giving all sorts of different results (I know you know that...).

Comment: I gave an example. $\mathcal{N}(A^{\star}A)=\mathcal{N}(A)$ is the general principle, which holds for any closed densely-defined linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space.

Comment: Are u sure that $A^*A=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with $f$ continuously differentiable periodic functions on $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: $A=A^{\star}$ for the $A$ I gave. Read very careful what I wrote about defining the domain of $H$ and you'll see why $H=A^{2}$. $Hf$ is required to be in $L^{2}$ space, and I should have been explicit about that. The same is true of $Af$ on its domain.

Comment: That with being in $L^2$ is fine since it is required to be continuously differentiable rather than merely differentiable. But I'm not sure about $A=A^*$. Obviously $A$ is symmetric by periodicity. But what about weak derivatives that could in principle belong to the domain of $A^*$?

Comment: @Freeze_S : Yes, if you take $\mathcal{D}(A)$ to be the set of $f \in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ which are (a.e.) continuous on $[0,2\pi]$, periodic, and absolutely continuous with $f' \in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$, then you have a perfect densely-defined closed selfadjoint linear operator. You can prove this for yourself by supposing that $g \in \mathcal{D}(A^{\star})$ and use piecewise linear test functions $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ to prove that $g$ is absolutely continuous from the relation $(Af,g)=(f,h)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. Try it, and I think you'll learn some interesting things.

Comment: @Freeze_S : The other interesting thing you gain from knowing $A$ is selfadjoint is that the spectral theorem tells you $\{ f \in L^{2} : \sum_{n}|(f,e^{inx})|^{2}n^{2} < \infty \}=\mathcal{D}(A)$, which means that $\sum_{n}n^{2}|(f,e^{inx})|^{2} < \infty$ iff $f$ is equal a.e. to an absolutely continuous function on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ and $f' \in L^{2}$. Sobolev spaces in 1-d are very different, nice and classical.

Comment: Oh I was curious about that proof anyway (trying to do that some weeks ago). I guess I will open another thread on this. Besides another question: How does one conclude that these are the only eigenvalues and is it true that the eigenspaces are two dimensional except for $\lambda=0$?

Comment: @Freeze_S : Once you know $Af=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(f,e^{inx})ne^{inx}$, then $Hf=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(f,e^{inx})n^{2}e^{inx}$ is more or less evident. That gives the dimension of the eigenspaces right away.

Comment: Yes sure but there could be more eigenfunctions for $H$ than for $A$, couldn't it? I mean $Af=\lambda f$ implies $A^2f=\lambda^2 f$ but $A^2 f=\kappa f$ doesn't imply $Af=\sqrt{\kappa}f$ in general, or?

Comment: @Freeze_S : Yes, but not for $\lambda=0$ because $(A^{2}f,f)=(Af,Af)=\|Af\|^{2}$ for $f \in \mathcal{D}(A^{2})$. More generally, if $A$ is closed and densely-defined, then $A^{\star}A$ is selfadjoint on its natural domain consisting of all $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ for which $Af \in \mathcal{D}(A^{\star})$, and $A^{\star}Af=0$ implies $Af=0$.